# Twitter integration into iPhone app

Tags: iphone, twitter

I am using MGTwitterEngine in my iPhone application.
It is working great of for every other functionality than search user.
I have tried to integrate search functionality of twitter i.e. GET users/search | dev.twitter.com.

but didnt get any success.

i have also tried by changing path of TWITTER_DOMAIN to @"api.twitter.com/1"
but no success.
i am getting Response code 403.

Can some one please please guide me solve this Search user functionality?

Regards,
Sanket

Comment: What were you not able to implement exactly? What code do you have so far?

Comment: I have also tried by changing path of TWITTER_DOMAIN to @"api.twitter.com/1"
but no success.
i am getting Response code 403.

Answer (score 0):

You can login with twitter. This doc explain step by steps[Twitter Login](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_-4eQGpdqTBcEFqWkF2djN4eFE)